# More intuitive career profile UX

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

In overall, I'm very satisfied with profile design, but apparently some people don't see the buttons for expanding experience/career/etc records, and thus are missing the important info.

In fact, during the last month I've been asked by recruiters twice already to go through all of my past work places, even though my profile IMO is self sufficient. I assume they thought those gray triangles are just design elements, not buttons:

[image]

Comment: First off, recruiters will often ask you to go through past experiences in your own words regardless of what's written on the CV. As far as the UX elements, however, I totally agree. If it's important it should be immediately visible. It shouldn't hide behind expansion toggles.

Comment: @J.Steen Agree. I explicitly asked if they see experience descriptions, and received a negative answer.

Comment: Maybe the simple resolution to this is just to state "Show" or "Hide" rather than the silly triangles.  Or right under the tags something to the effect of `show experience and highlights at this company...` as a hyperlink that actually expands the experience level, etc.

Comment: This is due to the fact that browser makers were slow to implement details/summary: the users are not yet used to disclosure widgets.